# Anyone use SonarCube with ObjectScript

Tags: sonarqube, intersystems-cache, intersystems, objectscript

We use InterSystems Cache which has a development language called ObjectScript (kinda looks like VB).

It has it's own IDE called Studio.

Has anyone been able to successfully use SonarQube with Studio/ObjectScript?

There is no plugin for it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that we'll see Caché Object Script plugin to SonarQube in production soon.
See discussion about this [here](https://community.intersystems.com/post/announce-java-package-import-xmlsexport-sources)

Comment: And the recent news: https://community.intersystems.com/post/static-code-analysis-tool-objectscript-presented-phoenix